# Capture first 8 characters Perl

Tags: perl

How could I take 8 characters of a string, for example:

If I has like this:

```
my $word ="take first 8 characters";
```

How could I print this: `take fir`?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use [`substr`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr.html).

```
print substr($word, 0, 8);
```

Answer (score 9):

Use the built in [`substr`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr.html) function. `substr($string, $start, $length)`

Answer (score 6):

From **perlfaq4**: [How can I access or change N characters of a string?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-can-I-access-or-change-N-characters-of-a-string?):

> You can access the first characters of a string with substr(). To get
>   the first character, for example, start at position 0 and grab the
>   string of length 1.

```perl
my $string = "Just another Perl Hacker";
my $first_char = substr( $string, 0, 1 ); # 'J'
```

(See the rest of the article for guidance on *changing* part of a string.)